# Can I merge vertices from different objects with subdivision modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]

Hi, please can help me?

Is it possible to make them stay together and look smooth even though they are different objects? It is for a body that I want to put several optional hands and legs and keep the option to change the amount of the sub depending on the game and the quality needed at each moment.

[image]

I did not find this answer on the internet, thanks you very much for helping me.
Hugs!

Comment: I don’t think this is possible. It needs to all be one object, unless you can guarantee they will all un-subdivide in the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it could be possible with some hacks:

[image]

Outline disabled:

[image]

1. One extra loop is required, which after subdivision hides using mask modifier.
2. To smooth normals you can use data transfer modifier to copy normals from one object to another.

Maybe copping normals is enough for your task.

Vertex Group for mask:

[image]

Vertex Group for data transfer:

[image]

[image]